# Check if value in object is null or empty javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

That's my problem: I could have this array of objects:

```
[{
    "name": "Alex",
    "code": "05422180283",
    "pIva": "05422180283",
    "subCode": null
}, {
    "name": "John",
    "code": null,
    "pIva": null,
    "subCode": "IT"
}, {
    "name": "Billy",
    "code": null,
    "pIva": null,
    "subCode": "IT"
}, {
    "name": "Tom",
    "code": null,
    "pIva": null,
    "subCode": "IT"
}]
```

This json is used in a form by an `ng-repeat` and the null field should be  filled. When the submit button is pressed the system should be check if there are still empty field. So the situation could be this one now:

```
[{
    "name": "Alex",
    "code": "05422180283",
    "pIva": "05422180283",
    "subCode": null
}, {
    "name": "John",
    "code": "88985556",
    "pIva": "1919ASVVV",
    "subCode": "9991VVVV"
}, {
    "name": "Billy",
    "code": "89952366555",
    "pIva": "BB588918989",
    "subCode": "ASA234434"
}, {
    "name": "Tom",
    "code": null,
    "pIva": "541198198",
    "subCode": "ACEVV9999"
}]
```

As you can see there are 2 null fields. In this situation the system should be advise the user that there are 2 empty fields. (with an alert or something like that). Otherwise the user can submit the form without any problem. This is what i've done so far:

```
angular.forEach($scope.myArray, function(items){
                if(_.chain(items).find(_.isNull).isNull().value()) {
                    //console.log('Found one');
                    formHasEmptyFields = true;
                } else {
                    //console.log('Did not find one');
                    formHasEmptyFields = false;
                }
                if(_(items).find(_.isNull) === null) {
                    //console.log('Found one');
                    formHasEmptyFields = true;
                } else {
                    //console.log('Did not find one');
                    formHasEmptyFields = false;
                }
            });
            if(formHasEmptyFields == true) {
                alert('There are empty fields');
            } else {
                submitFunction($scope.myArray);
            }
```

But it doesn't work because seems that it check only the last object. In fact, if I fill the last object in the form it doesn't show me the alert. Any idea? `$scope.myArray` is my array of objects of course

Comment: can you please attach your html form aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that although `formHasEmptyFields` *does* get set to `true` when there is a `null`, it gets overwritten with `false` again in the next iteration.

So, to solve this, only set `formHasEmptyFields = false;` once, before the loop, and inside the loop, only keep the code that sets it to `true`.

Having said that, a `some` or `every` method is more useful for this scenario than a `forEach` loop. You may want to use that instead.

Comment: So, you mainly mean to delete the else conditions?

Comment: Indeed, drop them.

Answer (score 1):

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example) for `some`

```
const hasItemWhithFalsyCode = items.some(x => !x.code);
```

You can do all sorts of stuff, like filter out the items without a code

```
const itemsWithTruthyCode = items.filter(x => x.code);
```

To explictly check for `null`

```
const hasItemWhithNullCode = items.some(x => x.code === null);
```

Comment: Indeed, using `some` is better than `forEach` in this scenario: it exits the loop as soon as there is a certain condition. It would be useful for the OP if you would provide the code specifically for their case.